# Spyder will not launch on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu, spyder

I have installed python 2.7, 3.5, Anaconda2 and Anaconda3. I cannot get spyder v3.01, 3.00, 2.3.9, or 2.3.8 to launch in any of these environments. From the command line, typing `spyder` or even `python spyder --reset` result in

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a fix?

Comment: Please post some minimal information: what operating system are you using? what are your Qt and PyQt versions? Besides, if you installed Spyder correctly, you shouldn't need to write `python spyder` to launch it, just `spyder`.

Comment: Sorry! I had meant to include it's a fresh install of ubuntu 16.10. Also, I just noticed the spyder_crash.log file in my home directory. It turns out in ubuntu 16.10, they removed an old / unmaintained package "QtWebkit", which spyder needs to load. I was able to make it work in anaconda3 by running "sudo apt-get install python3-pyside.qtwebkit", but it still crashes when I try to do the same for python2.7 ("sudo apt-get install python-pyside.qtwebkit").

Comment: Ha, I had typed the OS in the title. I guess I'm not (quite) as sleep deprived as I originally thought. ;) But I am having trouble reading. For python2.7 I'm using pyqt4 (anaconda2-4.1.1) and for python3, I'm using pyqt5 (anaconda3-4.2.0).

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your title well. I missed you are in Ubuntu :-). About what you said: 1. You don't have to mix Anaconda and Ubuntu packages to make Spyder working. The fact that you're doing it means that you didn't install Anaconda correctly. 2. Spyder 3.0 doesn't work with PySide. 3. Anaconda contains **all** packages Spyder needs to run, so you have to be sure to only use those and not the ones that come with Ubuntu (none of them).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. What I mean is I've tried installing spyder on the native python2.7 environment, then Anaconda2, then Anaconda3, and at each stage, spyder crashed. To verify I didn't do something wonky, I uninstalled all spyders and Anacondas, then reinstalled a fresh Anaconda2 (bash Anaconda2-4.1.1-Linux-x86_64.sh). As expected, "which python" and "which spyder" now both point to the Anaconda2 path. Running "spyder" from the command line causes a core dump.

Comment: Doing the same "clean install" with Anaconda3 (Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh) produces a working spyder3, now, so I am assuming there was some subtle mixing of versions going on before. I still would like to get Anaconda2-4.1.1 working in parallel, however, because I need to test code in both spyder environments (qt4 and qt5).

Comment: Instead of trying to install a different version of Anaconda (which is what's probably the cause of your problems), you just need to create a new conda environment (http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) and install qt4 on it.

Comment: Creating a new Python2.7 environment and adding either version of spyder that is available from Continuum didn't fix the problem (still a core dump). This also doesn't explain why a "clean" install of Anaconda2-4.1.1 has a core dump (there was only one version of Anaconda at that point). I did notice in sys.path there was _one_ path that was not within the environment. Popping this entry allows me to get spyder launching, as did adding `sys.path.pop(7)` to the spyder launcher. This is hacky, for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Okay I finally figured out the problem, which likely only affects those who have first tried to install things like spyder in their default python distribution (even if this was later "removed"). The solution was first to start a python shell and check `sys.path`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

Make sure all the listed paths are within your current python environment. For me, all paths included my anaconda installation path except one, which started with `/home/jack/.local`. Not sure how that got in there. Removing this from the path (using `sys.path.pop()` or `sys.path.remove()` in python fixed the problem.

To permanently fix the problem, I simply removed the "leftovers" from previously installed python packages that were hanging around in my `.local` directory. Now everything is great.

Thanks to Carlos Cordoba for the hints, and (more importantly) for spyder!

Cheers!